# Order by date with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

Ok, my goal is to have a whole lot of posts displayed on this website, and they are retrieved from a server that organizes them in a way that is not by date, but I want to organize them by date.

So, currently I have something like this going on on my website:

```
  <div class="col-md-6" id="listing1">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/f7rJAZ7.gif">
            <div class="caption">
              <h5 class="pull-right">Posted <span class="date" data-date="1402700296">2014-06-13 5PM</span></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8af2eJX.gif">
            <div class="caption">
              <h5 class="pull-right">Posted <span class="date" data-date="1402696287">2014-06-13 4PM</span></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uaJdSdx.jpg">
            <div class="caption">
              <h5 class="pull-right">Posted <span class="date" data-date="1402673458">2014-06-13 10AM</span></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And I have this JQuery down at the bottom of the document attempting to handle and sort those posts, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all, because it leaves them as is

```
$("#listing1 .col-sm-12").sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date($(a + " .thumbnail .caption .pull-right .date").attr("data-date")) > new Date($(b + " .thumbnail .caption .pull-right .date").attr("data-date"));
}).each(function(){
  $("#listing1").prepend(this);
})
```

I have the latest version of JQuery included, everything is up to date. Absolutely everything else works except the date sorting - which will be vitally important once I start including these posts from a second source, also sorting them in a fashion that is not by date and is not similar to the first source's sorting.

I understand that my nesting is a little crazy, but it's the best looking thing I found in Bootstrap 3, and none of my comrades want it changed.

Comment: Better to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for `data-*` attributes...

Comment: I think better use server side language with can make DB query with sort order.

Comment: War10ck: Thanks :) dfsq incorporated that into his answer, so now I am using that. -- imRcH: I'm not directly interacting with a database is the only problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your script:

```
$("#listing1 .col-sm-12").sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date($(".date", a).data("date")) - new Date($(".date", b).data("date"));
}).appendTo("#listing1");
```

The part `$(".date", a)` is equivalent to `$(a).find(".date")`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26zM/1/

Comment: Well, I don't want to return an ordered list of the dates (though that's the closest I've gotten to the right result, so thank you), I want to return all of the posts, ordered by their respective dates. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Sorry I just removed images from the demo to make sorting result clear. http://jsfiddle.net/Z26zM/2/

Comment: Ah, I forgot how much less data I had in the example than on the actual site and didn't realize until now the difference. This works quite nearly perfectly! Turns out that I had it reversed (it was showing the oldest posts first), so I just changed `return new Date($(".date", a).data("date")) - new Date($(".date", b).data("date"));` to `return new Date($(".date", b).data("date")) - new Date($(".date", a).data("date"));` I'm not sure if that was the smartest way to fix it, but it worked haha. Again, thank you.